# How do I block storage bin for putaway in S4HANA?

Tags: abap, bapi, s4hana, sap-ewm

I need to block a bin other than the bin determined during creation of the warehouse task - bin adjacent to the determined bin. I can manually block the storage bin for putaway via /SCWM/LS02 like below:

[image: /SCWM/LS02 screen sample]

However, I need to do this via enhancement during posting of the warehouse task. I put the code in a BADI for updating the warehouse task (enhancement spot /SCWM/ES_CORE_SB), and it is quite difficult to replicate the process in the /SCWM/LS02. It involves manipulating memory values via a dialog, then importing them back again into the main program before calling the function module for saving the changes (but still not successful in making the changes "stick")

The custom status has already been setup and can be used as reason for blocking the bin for putaway.

Does anyone know of any FM or BAPI I can use to block the storage bin with a custom status? OR have tried blocking a storage bin via ABAP? Googled but found none. Have looked and tried FMs of FG CRMBSVA but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can block/unblock a storage bin for stock putaway/removal with the /SCWM/BIN_BLOCK_USER function. The function does block/unblock a bin. However it doesn't set user status, which is optional in /SCWM/LS02 too.